# Java array length less than 0?

Tags: java, arrays

I was going through an open source project where they were creating an output stream, and came across the following method:

```
@Override public void write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length) {
    if (buffer == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("buffer is null");
    }
    if (buffer.length < 0) { // NOTE HERE
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("buffer length < 0");
    }
    if (offset < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.format("offset %d < 0", offset));
    }
    if (length < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.format("length %d < 0", length));
    }
    if (offset > buffer.length || length > buffer.length - offset) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.format("offset %d + length %d > buffer"                                                       " length %d", offset, length, buffer.length));
    }
}
```

So the `byte[] buffer` is just a normal old `byte[]`. We know it's not null. Is it even possible to make it have a length of less than 0? Like, could it be done with **reflection** and that's what they're guarding against?

Comment: What do you mean "we know it's not `null`"?

Comment: @EdwardThomson: I think because the first statement checks `buffer == null`

Comment: Maybe somewhere else in that project it is a convention that `-1` is valid as a way to say that an index is invalid or something like that and here it is finally turned into an exception.

Comment: My guess is, this is a typo and it should actually be `buffer.length <= 0`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `<=` makes no sense. This should be `==`. And a typo wouldn't be reproduced in the text of the exception.

Comment: @thalador There can be no such convention. You physically **cannot** make `array.length < 0`.

Comment: @dystroy It's still less stupid than [`if (size > INT_MAX)`](http://use.perl.org/use.perl.org/_Aristotle/journal/33448.html)

Comment: @millimoose Where do you see that ?

Comment: @dystroy Not in the sample (the code bit is a link), just pointing out that sillier runtime checks were done.

Comment: @millimoose That could at least be explainable. If `size` is a `long`, the statement makes complete sense. If `size` then changes (later on) to be an `int`, then the comparison doesn't make sense but might not get caught and eliminated. A `byte[]`'s length has never in the history of a project been < 0.

Comment: @GregHewgill: oh, i misunderstood.  I thought the assertion was that the null-check was also unnecessary.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik true, but -1 can still be a result from a method like `findSubstringInString(..)` to indicate no result. Of course using this index will lead to an error.

Comment: You should not try to guard against random bugs in the JVM just because you can imagine them.

Comment: @thalador There are plenty of cases when an int can be -1. There are zero cases when an array's length can be -1 (which is what's being checked here).

Comment: What's strange with this method is that it writes nothing. Was the author too occupied by the assertions to write something useful ?

Comment: Anyway, OP, we can now safely conclude that you are welcome to raise an issue at that open source project's bug tracker!

Comment: @dystroy No, it's meant to do nothing useful. It's declaration is `final static public OutputStream NULL = new OutputStream() {`

Comment: It's the *Null-object* pattern. Makes sense now, a programmer implements **nothing** so he has that urge to try and make it do **something**.

Comment: @dystroy: I *have* seen people been over-cautious and check for `<=` where a `==` would have been enough.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've seen plenty of those, too, and wrote some myself as well, but always in cases where the language will have no issue with that var being < 0. The check at hand is on the order of checking that an unsigned value is < 0 -- say you check that a `char` is < 0.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, this can never happen. The length is guaranteed to be non-negative as per the Java specifications.

> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> - The public final field length, which contains the number of components
>     of the array. **length may be positive or zero**.

Source: [JLS §10.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7)

As mprivat mentioned, if you ever try to create an array of negative size, a [NegativeArraySizeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NegativeArraySizeException.html) will be thrown.

Comment: @Reimeus: Because programmers never make any mistakes and always write the most optimal code.

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe it's possible. Even through reflection, it is guarded with NegativeArraySizeException

Comment: I made an effort to alter the length of an array reflectively, but found myself unable to do so. The `getDeclaredFields()` method returns an empty result for an array input, and the `Array` reflection class understandably has no such method (because why would you ever want it?) I think short of modifying memory directly there'd be no way to do this, but I doubt there's actually a check that would prevent this. Of course, if a program is modifying memory on you, you have bigger problems than you can catch with a parameter check...

Comment: Yeah, I think that was just bad code. The only to make this happen would be to do some sort of byte code modification somehow. And frankly, even with that, I'm not 100% sure you could if the length is somehow coded as an unsigned number (which I suspect is the case).

Comment: I don't think it is, because you can't compile `int[] a = new int[3000000000];` - I suspect it is stored as an `int` like any other.

Comment: You're definitely right. Because `int[] a = new int[-1];` does compile. Of course it doesn't run as expected but it compiles. Plus there's no such thing as an unsigned int in the JVM. Duh. Good question though.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an exception handling issue.  You're allowed to create an array with a negative size in Java - it wont even throw an exception when you compile it.  But at run time, your program won't run until this is corrected. (It will throw a `NegativeArraySizeException`.)

The problem is with this exception being thrown at run time instead of compile time - That's why the exception has been handled with `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: "*You're allowed to create an array with a negative size in Java*" - no, you are not. You can *write* `new int[-1]` but the JVM will not create such an array. No Java array object will ever have a negative length.